# Avoid Target Url in spring security for an action of a controller

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using spring security `spring-security-core:2.0-RC2`.
I wrote the below given statement in `Config.groovy` to set default URL of my grails application.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
```

But now I want to make a action such that I can avoid default target URL and after login I can move direct to given action.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this and check. '/home' is where you would specify your controller and action.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/home'
```